# TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from int_const 0 to address requested

Tags: solidity

```
 constructor(string memory enterOrganizationName) public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    status = true;
    addUser(0, "", "");
    addUser(owner, 'Creator and Owner of Smart Contract', "");
    organizationName = enterOrganizationName;
    numberOfUsers = 0;
    addEndorsee(0, "");
    numberOfEndorsees = 0;
}
```

giving below error.

```
TypeError: Invalid type for argument in function call. Invalid implicit conversion from int_const 0 to address requested.
        addUser(0, "", "");
                ^
```

I'm still new in Ethereum platform so I'm not sure what that error means.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems the type of the first argument of your `addUser` function is an `address`. If you want to initialize it with the "address 0", you have to explicitly convert it like that : `addUser(address(0), "", "")`

Answer (score 0):

This Address(0) worked for me.